# Is there a more efficient way to loop through multiple lists

Tags: c#, .net

I have 4 lists of strings - These are all identical in length

```
var nameList;
var dateList;
var versionList;
var downloadList;
```

I'm currently looping through each list individually and then adding the contents of each list into a concurrent queue

```
var concurrentNameQueue= new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var concurrentDateQueue= new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var concurrentVersionQueue= new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var concurrentDownloadQueue= new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

foreach (var name in nameList)
{
    concurrentNameQueue.Enqeue(name);
}

foreach (var date in dateList)
{
    concurrentDateQueue.Enqeue(date);
}

foreach (var version in versionList)
{
    concurrentVersionQueue.Enqeue(version);
}

foreach (var download in downloadList)
{
    concurrentDownloadQueue.Enqeue(download);
}
```

This process seems awfully repetitive and got me wondering if there is a more efficient way to loop through all these lists

Is there a more efficent way to do this?

Comment: It seems that instead of 4 lists you might want to consider a class with 4 properties, and then one list of the class

Comment: Also where do you initialize the queues?

Comment: I updated my post to include the initialization of the queues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can write an extension method and then call it:

   ```
   public static void Enqueue<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue, IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
       foreach (var item in items)
           queue.Enqueue(item);
   }

   concurrentNameQueue.Enqueue(nameList);
   concurrentDateQueue.Enqueue(dateList);
   concurrentVersionQueue.Enqueue(versionList);
   concurrentDownloadQueue.Enqueue(downloadList);
   ```
2. Or as you are initializing the list just above then use the [second
   constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267303(v=vs.110).aspx) that requires an `IEnumerable<T>` as input:

   ```
   var concurrentNameQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(nameList);
   var concurrentDateQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(dateList);
   var concurrentVersionQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(versionList);
   var concurrentDownloadQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(downloadList);
   ```

---

But as I mentioned in my comment it seems like you should create a single class with 4 properties, one for each of name, date, version and download. Then you have one list of that class instead of keeping 4 lists synced.

Comment: @LostBoy - that is for sure a much better design

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making multiple list, use data structure that has multiple properties

Thats the advantage of OOP. Create single list of this instead

```
public class DownloadItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Download { get; set; }
}
```